# Fluent NHibernate Mapping help

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent

I am getting the following error:

Invalid index 3 for this OracleParameterCollection with Count=3

when i am attempting to insert a new column into a table.

my entity class is:

```
public class Operator
{
    public Operator()
    {
        this.OperatorMemberships = new List<OperatorMembership>();
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int OperatorMembershipId { get; set; }
    public virtual int SchemeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<OperatorMembership> OperatorMemberships { get; set; }
}

public class OperatorMembership
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int OperatorId { get; set; } // delete
    public virtual int UserRoleId { get; set; } // delete
    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
    public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
}
```

My mappings are:

```
public OperatorMap()
    {
        Table("OPERATOR");
        Id(x => x.Id, "OPERATOR_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.SchemeId, "SCHEME_ID");
        Map(x => x.Description, "DESCRIPTION");
        //HasMany(x => x.OperatorMemberships).Inverse().AsBag().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        HasMany(x => x.OperatorMemberships).Inverse().AsBag();
        //References(x => x.SchemeServices, "OPERATOR_ID");
    }
}

public class OperatorMembershipMap : ClassMap<OperatorMembership>
{
    public OperatorMembershipMap()
    {
        Table("USER_OPERATOR_MEMBERSHIP");
        Id(x => x.Id, "USER_OPERATOR_MEMBERSHIP_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.OperatorId, "OPERATOR_ID");
        Map(x => x.UserRoleId, "USER_ROLE_ID");

        References(x => x.Operator).Column("OPERATOR_ID"); ;
        References(x => x.UserRole).Column("USER_ROLE_ID");
    }
}
```

the code to insert the new row is:

```
public int AddOperatorMembership(int operatorId, int userRoleId)
    {
        OperatorMembership op = new OperatorMembership();
        op.OperatorId = operatorId;
        op.UserRoleId = userRoleId;
        _provider.AddEntity(op);

        return op.Id;
    }
```

and my database table is:

```
USER_OPERATOR_MEMBERSHIP_ID -- OPERATOR_ID -- USER_ROLE_ID
```

any help would be good, i am sure there are some very clever fluent nhibernate developers out there who can spot the error straight away.

many thanks.

Randolf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mapping the referenced entities AND the foreign key :

```
public OperatorMembershipMap()
{
    Table("USER_OPERATOR_MEMBERSHIP");
    Id(x => x.Id, "USER_OPERATOR_MEMBERSHIP_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    // Map(x => x.OperatorId, "OPERATOR_ID");
    // Map(x => x.UserRoleId, "USER_ROLE_ID");

    References(x => x.Operator).Column("OPERATOR_ID"); ;
    References(x => x.UserRole).Column("USER_ROLE_ID");
}
```

You can also remove the foreign keys from your entity :

```
public class OperatorMembership
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    // public virtual int OperatorId { get; set; } // delete
    // public virtual int UserRoleId { get; set; } // delete
    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
    public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: if I remove the properties then i cannot access them with my code for an update with these values: op.OperatorId = operatorId;        op.UserRoleId = userRoleId;

Comment: And you can use op.Operator = session.Load(operatorId)

Comment: hi mathieu, how would i save a new operatormembership row? if i do not have the 2 properties then i will not be able to save, the operatormembership table is a lookup table for operator and userrole.

Comment: You don't have to map the relationship table : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Nhibernate_Made_Simple.aspx

Comment: Cheers Mate, you were right i just didnt need to map the columns, but still left them in the class entity and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I too came across the same issue and ended up googling for half a day but no success. The above answer given by Mathieu seemd relevant and i tried the same but did not work for me. Then i tried with removing references and keeping the properties intact, it worked for me and hope will work for you as well.

```
    Table("USER_OPERATOR_MEMBERSHIP");
    Id(x => x.Id, "USER_OPERATOR_MEMBERSHIP_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.OperatorId, "OPERATOR_ID");
    Map(x => x.UserRoleId, "USER_ROLE_ID");

    //References(x => x.Operator).Column("OPERATOR_ID"); ;
    //References(x => x.UserRole).Column("USER_ROLE_ID");
```

Remove the same from class as well

```
public class OperatorMembership
{
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual int OperatorId { get; set; } // delete
     public virtual int UserRoleId { get; set; } // delete
     //public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
     //public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
}
```